# How to install/use php on mac v 10.7.2

Tags: php, macos, osx-lion

i'm your average college student interested in using PHP. Could anyone give me a 101 on how to install/enable it on a mac version 10.7.2 using simple, plain language? I will appreciate any and all help!!

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No Need to Install PHP or Apache, They already ship with Mac 10.7

These are the basic steps you need to take for PHP and Apache to work together:

- Enable PHP in you httpd.conf file located - /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
- Setup your php.ini - sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
- Enable the Apache web server located in the Sharing > Web Sharing

### Enable PHP in Apache

Find this setting in your httpd.conf file

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

And, uncomment it like

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

This guide explains setting up MySQL and VirtualHost on Mac. I have been using this setup for over six months. Also, worked on the 10.7 early releases just fine.
http://superfancy.net/coding/php-mysql-apache-in-mac-osx-leopard/

### Shell Commands to Start and Stop Apache on Mac

Start Apache

```
sudo apachectl start
```

Restart Apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

(edited to remove typo in restart command)

Comment: Thank you for responding and for this help! i guess my problem now is, where and how do i find my "Httpd.conf" file? i'm looking at the guide now and i'm not sure where it is.

also, when i do "show invisible files" i have no clue what to do next, i can't find the /etc folder

Comment: <StartRant>I swear. Apple makes some things easy and other things impossible to figure out on your own without pushing lots of random key combinations. </StartRant> After you unhide the files. Go Finder > Preferences > Sidebar > Devices section and enable your whole drive to show up on the side. Now, you can drag these shortcuts to your sidebar for quick access. 

Finder tip: Enable Path Bar, goto Finder > View > Show Path Bar - This makes Mac more Windows like in my opinion and helps major.

Comment: "drag these short cuts" i'm not sure what you're referring to there... i seriously am a noob when it comes to this. sorry for all the dumb questions and thanks for your help! I'm having a big problem with these two steps;
1. Enable PHP in you httpd.conf file located - /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
2. Setup your php.ini - sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini

Comment: now when i look up "httpd.conf" in my finder, i get two files: php_core2 and php_core3, is this what i'm looking for? am i doing the wrong thing?

Comment: i have one question, so now that i deleted the comment. what purpose does apache serve me? all i want to do is learn php, i mean i have apache started, but do i need to do anything with it? configure it in any way? i got it wokring! that tutorial helped me set it up thank you!

Comment: Hey @jordan, Glad you got it figured out. As far as apache, you need it to serve up the PHP, and it must run while you process your .php pages.

Answer (score 0):

PHP5 should be already installed, it's just disabled.  Open the Apache config file with a text editor it's at
   /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Now find the line which reads: "#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so" and delete the comment (hash) from the beginning of the line and save the file (you'll need admin permissions to do this)

Now restart Apache - from the Terminal app type: sudo apachectl graceful
It will ask for your admin password

PHP should now be working..