# fatal error: call to undefined function mssql_connect() on mac osx lion 10.7.4

Tags: sql-server, php

So, I can execute php scripts from the terminal, but when the script tries to connect to the database using mssql_connect(), I run into this problem. I have gone through almost all of the sources available for this problem. But, it seems like I have something different. I'm fairly new to Mac, but I have followed most of the steps like uncommenting

```
 #LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

from the httpd.conf file, turning on the web sharing under system preferences. However, I'm not sure if I need to uncomment php_mysql/(i).dll from the php.ini file as well, since I'm using ms sql and not my sql. Also, I do not seem to have php_mssql70.dll like it was suggested in one of the forums I ran into during my search. But, there are 2 lines in my .ini file that read

```
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll   
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll  \\Yes. They both read the same thing.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please? I'm not sure if the information I gave is sufficient. But yes, I think I have read and tried to emulate 90% of the forums that claim to solve this problem.

NOTE: This post seemed quite close to what I am trying, given that the user is a noob at this. I haven't really set up PHP, Apache, etc by myself since I have only worked with Php and MySQL in school till now.
[How to install/use php on mac v 10.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440948/how-to-install-use-php-on-mac-v-10-7-2)

Comment: They are not the same thing, one is mSsql, the other is mYsql

Comment: Do you have a MS database on your Mac??? Or you mean mysql?

Comment: You need to have also this in your php.ini :  `extension=php_mssql.dll`

Comment: I do understand that mYsql and mSsql are two different things. I'm not sure if I have the mSsql db setup. How do i check that? I'm sorry for dumb questions... :/

Comment: @koopajah dll on mac? You sure?

Comment: I have nothing like extension=php_mssql.dll in my .ini file at all. :(

Comment: @WatchfulProtector this might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846438/using-mssql-methods-freetds-php-and-apache-on-mac-os-x

Comment: ^ Thanks for the link. So, it means that I MUST install FreeTDS right? And there is no other way out?

Comment: Yes, mssql is not supported on platforms other than windows, so this is the only way.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller : I have been trying to install freeTDS using the above link. But, when I paste the 
    
  "./configure --prefix=/usr/local/freetds --sysconfdir=/usr/local/freetds/conf/freetds --disable-libiconv --disable-odbc",   
type "make" and press ENTER, it runs and displays a set of lines and the last 2 lines are :  
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `make': machine `make' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub make failed 
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're *not* on Windows you need to ignore anyone mentioning anything containing '*.dll'.

Look for `extensions.ini` which should in the same folder as php.ini, or in a folder very close to it, and you should be able to enable it from there, it should be a .so file. If it is not already there then the extension is not installed at all. I have no idea how to add PHP extensions on OSX, though. :I

Comment: I cannot find the extensions.ini at all. But, like dev-null-dweller suggested in his comment, do I just install FreeTDS and expect it to work? Because what is suggested here : 
      http://superfancy.net/php-mysql-apache-in-mac-osx-leopard/
doesn't seem to work either. I do all the steps. And then the test.php just doesn't work. However, he discusses mysql and not mSsql.

Comment: @WatchfulProtector Honestly, I've hardly ever ~used~ a Mac, let alone tried to run PHP on it. But it's *nix, and whatever method you used to install PHP will probably also have the facility to install the mssql extension.